# Редактирование коллекции в PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

В общем, сделал класс, который содержит несколько простых строковых полей.

Сделал вот так:

```
  [DisplayName("ФИО")]
    public List<FIO> FioList
    {
        get
        {
            return _fioList.ToList();

        }
        set
        {
            _fioList= value;
        }
    }
    private List<FIO> _fioList;
```

(Возвращение копии, так задумано)

В общем, в PropertyGrid успешно появляется этот элемент и при нажатии на кнопку `...` открывается редактор коллекции. Только проблема в том, что я не попадаю в метод `Set`...

И в данном случае, я должен сделать, как описано в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4145641/4244707) ответе:
Т.е создать наследника от `CollectionEditor`, а в нем обратится к `context.Instance` и там выполнить присвоение или есть другие варианты?

Comment: Логично, что set не вызывается, коллекция же по сути та же самая остается

Comment: Ок, тогда получается, что то решение из ответа верное для моего случая.